# writeOGR R and add an icon symbol

Tags: r, gps

I am wondering if there is a way to add an icon symbol to the R code I am using to export data in GPX format.

In the navigation program I import the GPX file into all of the of coordinates are shown with an icon like a blue circle or an X. Right now I have to manually go into the program and make all of the coordinates icons and I would like to know if I can automate it within R. Maybe with pch= something for a symbol shape and col= something for a color.

Here is some example data:

```
 dput(head(location_information))
structure(list(Stratum = c(9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10), Long = c(-74.7481648257133, 
-74.8131391902885, -74.8808092556099, -74.8653903776827, -74.7982608783084, 
-74.7124840980305), Lat = c(37.4333074571158, 37.2589604507964, 
37.0344661189436, 37.1094779835421, 36.9472164951635, 37.5385694318501
), Station = structure(c(449L, 450L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("10001", 
"10002", "10003", "10004", "10005", "11001", "11002", "11003", 
"11004", "11005", "11006", "11007", "12001", "12002", "12003", 
"12004", "12005", "12006", "13001", "13002", "13003", "13004", 
"13005", "13006", "13007", "13008", "13009", "13010", "13011", 
"14001", "14002", "14003", "14004", "14005", "14006", "15001", 
"15002", "15003", "15004", "15005", "15006", "15007", "15008", 
"15009", "15010", "15011", "15012", "15013", "15014", "15015", 
"15016", "15017", "15018", "15019", "15020", "15021", "15022", 
"15023", "16001", "16002", "16003", "16004", "16005", "17001", 
"17002", "17003", "17004", "17005", "17006", "17007", "17008", 
"17009", "18001", "18002", "18003", "18004", "18005", "18006", 
"18007", "18008", "18009", "18010", "18011", "18012", "18013", 
"18014", "18015", "18016", "18017", "18018", "18019", "18020", 
"18021", "18022", "18023", "18024", "18025", "18026", "18027", 
"18028", "18029", "18030", "18031", "18032", "18033", "18034", 
"18035", "18036", "18037", "18038", "18039", "18040", "18041", 
"19001", "19002", "19003", "19004", "19005", "19006", "19007", 
"19008", "19009", "19010", "19011", "19012", "19013", "19014", 
"19015", "19016", "19017", "19018", "19019", "19020", "19021", 
"19022", "19023", "20001", "20002", "21001", "21002", "21003", 
"21004", "21005", "21006", "21007", "21008", "21009", "21010", 
"21011", "21012", "21013", "21014", "21015", "21016", "21017", 
"21018", "21019", "21020", "21021", "22001", "22002", "22003", 
"22004", "22005", "22006", "22007", "22008", "22009", "22010", 
"22011", "22012", "22013", "22014", "22015", "22016", "22017", 
"22018", "22019", "22020", "22021", "22022", "22023", "22024", 
"22025", "22026", "22027", "22028", "23001", "23002", "23003", 
"23004", "23005", "23006", "23007", "23008", "23009", "23010", 
"23011", "23012", "23013", "23014", "23015", "23016", "23017", 
"23018", "23019", "23020", "23021", "23022", "23023", "23024", 
"23025", "23026", "23027", "23028", "23029", "23030", "23031", 
"23032", "23033", "23034", "23035", "23036", "23037", "23038", 
"23039", "23040", "23041", "23042", "23043", "23044", "23045", 
"23046", "23047", "23048", "23049", "23050", "23051", "23052", 
"23053", "23054", "23055", "23056", "23057", "23058", "23059", 
"23060", "23061", "23062", "23063", "23064", "23065", "23066", 
"23067", "23068", "23069", "23070", "23071", "23072", "23073", 
"23074", "23075", "23076", "23077", "23078", "23079", "23080", 
"23081", "23082", "23083", "23084", "23085", "23086", "23087", 
"23088", "23089", "23090", "23091", "23092", "23093", "23094", 
"23095", "23096", "23097", "23098", "23099", "23100", "23101", 
"23102", "23103", "24001", "24002", "24003", "24004", "24005", 
"24006", "24007", "24008", "24009", "25001", "25002", "25003", 
"25004", "25005", "25006", "25007", "25008", "25009", "25010", 
"25011", "25012", "25013", "26001", "26002", "26003", "26004", 
"26005", "27001", "27002", "27003", "27004", "27005", "27006", 
"27007", "27008", "27009", "27010", "27011", "27012", "27013", 
"27014", "27015", "27016", "27017", "27018", "27019", "28001", 
"28002", "28003", "29001", "29002", "29003", "29004", "29005", 
"29006", "29007", "29008", "29009", "29010", "29011", "29012", 
"29013", "29014", "29015", "29016", "29017", "29018", "29019", 
"29020", "29021", "29022", "29023", "29024", "30001", "30002", 
"30003", "30004", "30005", "30006", "30007", "30008", "30009", 
"30010", "30011", "30012", "30013", "30014", "30015", "30016", 
"30017", "30018", "30019", "31001", "31002", "31003", "31004", 
"31005", "31006", "31007", "31008", "31009", "31010", "31011", 
"31012", "31013", "31014", "31015", "31016", "31017", "31018", 
"31019", "31020", "31021", "31022", "31023", "31024", "31025", 
"31026", "31027", "31028", "31029", "31030", "31031", "31032", 
"31033", "31034", "31035", "31036", "33001", "33002", "33003", 
"33004", "33005", "33006", "33007", "34001", "34002", "34003", 
"34004", "34005", "35001", "35002", "35003", "35004", "35005", 
"35006", "35007", "35008", "35009", "35010", "35011", "35012", 
"35013", "37001", "37002", "37003", "38001", "38002", "9001", 
"9002"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Stratum", "Long", "Lat", 
"Station"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

#write location_information to GPX format for use with navigation software 
#make location_information a spatial points shapefile

#get lat/long from location_information
    xy2<-location_information[,c(2,3)]

 ll_points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy2,data=location_information,proj4string =CRS("+proj=longlat + ellps=WGS84"))
    class(ll_points)
    summary(ll_points)

#assign stationid labels with rosepoint nav software
ll_points2 <- spTransform(ll_points, CRS("+proj=longlat + ellps=WGS84"))

# rename Station column name for GPX formatting
ll_points2@data$name <- ll_points2@data$Station  

#Now only write the "name" field to the file
writeOGR(ll_points2["name"], driver="GPX", layer="waypoints", 
   dsn="gpxfile1.gpx", 
         dataset_options = "GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS=yes")

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you mean by an "icon symbol". In R parlance, this make very little sense.

Comment: In the navigation program I import the GPX file into all of the of coordinates are shown with an icon like a blue circle or an X.  Right now I have to manually go into the program and make all of the coordinates icons and I would like to know if I can automate it within R. Maybe with pch= something for a symbol shape and col= something for a color.